# Init.py goes for local settings.py rather than production settings.py DJANGO

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, settings

I created a setting folder with init.py, base.py, local. py and production.py but the Heroku address (host) is always trying to use local settings.

The app works fine when I access it from '127.0.0.1' but displays a 'disallowed host' error message when I try to access it from Heroku generated web address "XXX.herokuapp.com". "XXX.herokuapp.com" is only an allowed host when running production.py settings. Also, DEBUG = False in that particular setting file, so I suppose I shouldn't an error message detailed

Thanks for any help!

Here's my manage.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Kosmeoapp.settings.production')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's my **init**.py file :

```
from .base import *

from .production import *

try:
   from .local import *
except:
   pass
```

Here's my local.py file :

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0',
'127.0.0.1',
]

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XXX@gmail.com' #my gmail username
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXX' #my gmail password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "Lucas <XXXX>"


ADMINS = [('Lucas', EMAIL_HOST_USER)]
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #third party

    #own
    'pages',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'XXX.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'XXX.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'live-static/static-root'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here's my base.py file :

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XXX@gmail.com' #my gmail username
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXXX' #my gmail password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "Lucas <XXXX@gmail.com>"


ADMINS = [('Lucas', EMAIL_HOST_USER)]
MANAGERS = ADMINS


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #third party

    #own
    'pages',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'XXX.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'XXX.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'live-static/static-root'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'



# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here's my production.py file :

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['kosmeoapp.herokuapp.com']

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XXX@gmail.com' #my gmail username
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXX' #my gmail password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "Lucas <XXX@gmail.com>"


ADMINS = [('Lucas', EMAIL_HOST_USER)]
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #third party

    #own
    'pages',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'XXX.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'XXX.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES ['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'live-static/static-root'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'






# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Error message display :

```
allowed_hosts   
['0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1']
domain  
'kosmeoapp.herokuapp.com'
host    
'kosmeoapp.herokuapp.com'
msg 
("Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'kosmeoapp.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add "
 "'kosmeoapp.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.")
port    
''
self    
<WSGIRequest: GET '/admin'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update an env keys

Try putting a key like environment in env file as

```
ENVIRONMENT = TEST
```

And use manage.py to select the suitable settings for production or local settings.
Use if case. I have done this in my real life deployable project, and it works in both production and local environment.

I have these files in my settings folder
[image]

and I had updated my manage.py like these
[image]

> Here dep is the environment key which says whether the server is in development or deployment.

#### Conclusion

Add a key for the current environment and select the settings wisely.

Comment: Probably a silly question but where is/what is my env file?

Comment: There is nothing silly asking a question. An .env file is a file that is just like an external json file. Here in this file you declare variables. Later you can import it into your application. Furthur more, you can create a variable like `current_environement = LOCAL or SERVER ` and use different settings.py seperately.

Comment: So I need to create a .env file in the root but then what should I put in it? I'm very new to coding.

Comment: You can work with a variable(say x) too. Instead of an env file. If x =="LOCAL" use development.py as your settings.py file else use deplyment.py as your settings.py file.
[Hope this video helps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxQCAyiN6_w&ab_channel=JustDjangoJustDjango)

Answer (score 0):

In your Production code change the following setting in `manage.py`.

> Change the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to point to your `production.py` file.

`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<Your_app.settings.production>")`

Comment: My manage.py already points to my setting folder, therefore should be directed to production.py by __init__.py (which resides in the same folder). By directing it directly to production.py, the app shouldn't detect whether I should be using local or prod, right?

Comment: Your ```__init__.py``` contains imports from ```base.py```, ```local.py``` and ```production.py```. How will ```manage.py```  direct only to ```production.py``` ?

Comment: I'm confused with how init.py works. If I understand what your saying; my app is going to try first with production settings, and if I'm not an allowed host (such as 127.0.0.1) I'll bounce to using local settings?

Comment: I tried your solution, but the app keeps using local (I guess, taking that I see an error message a the bottom of the post). Weird thing is that locally, the app seems to be using productions settings as only 'xxx.herokuapp.com' is an allowed host. But when I'm launching the app through Heroku, it's using local settings...

Comment: Remove importing ```local.py``` and check if that works. @Lucas06140

Comment: I removed local.py from init.py and it looks like it takes production.py indeed. However, I now get a server error 500

Comment: @Lucas06140 If you get a Server error, Check heroku logs and know what's causing that.